# Types of connecting SQLServer database to flex3 application

Tags: .net, apache-flex, sql-server-2005, flex3

I connected flex application to SQLServer using .NET web service as a mediator.
I wanted to know what are the other methods to connect flex with database using .net?
that is how i can use remote service and data service instead of web service ?.

Im using webservice like:

```
<mx:WebService id="flextosql" wsdl="http://localhost:2209/Service1.asmx?WSDL" showBusyCursor="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use an HTTPService to call any web page to load information.  Doing this you can use flashvars (discouraged) or XML or of course just parse the contents (as either text or bytes)

More info on HTTPService here:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=data_access_2.html

You can also use AMF with RemoteObjects - There are a few providers of RemoteObjects for .NET such as WebOrb

More info on WebOrb here:

http://www.themidnightcoders.com/weborb/